# does variable contain variable

Tags: bash, echo, ifs

I have tried several things but can't get it to work.

I have an array element and I want to check to see if it contains a variable

```
if test "${${newpool[$a]}#*$pool}" != "${newpool[$a]}" ;then
        echo ${newpool[$a]}
fi
```

I need to know if ${newpool[$a]} contains $pool

I also tried a different method I found posted using a function, but it doesn't work either

```
contains() {
string="$1"
substring="$2"
if test "${string#*$substring}" != "$string"
then
    return 0    # $substring is in $string
else
    return 1    # $substring is not in $string
fi
}

help=()
help+="this is a test"
i="test"

test=$(contains ${help[0]} $i)

if [[ $test == 0 ]];then
    echo ${help[0]}
fi
```

Comment: Add output of `declare -p newpool pool a` to your question.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: BTW, be sure to test the case where your substring is `*` (passed with quotes on the invocation so it doesn't get replaced with a list of filenames) -- it'll break code that isn't careful about quoting.

Comment: As another aside, `help=(); help+="this is a test"` is **absolutely not** the same as `help=(); help+=( "this is a test" )`. Try putting `help+="this is another test"` and `help+=( "this is another test" )` after -- the first will append the string to the first element in the array, the second will append a new element.

Answer (score 1):

Using bashisms:

```
contains() {
  local string=$1 substring=$2
  [[ $string = *"$substring"* ]]
}
```

In POSIX sh:

```
contains() {
  string=$1; substring=$2
  case $string in
    *"$substring"*) return 0;;
    *)              return 1;;
  esac
}
```

In either case:

```
if contains foobar oo; then  echo "foobar contains oo"; fi
if contains foobar baz; then echo "foobar contains baz"; fi
```

will properly emit only `foobar contains oo`.